# GIT push step failing in Jenkins

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

Below code was working fine and all of the sudden it broken. I am using windows box.

```
 stage('Push')
    {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'gitlogin', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
                sh('git push --tags origin $BRANCH_NAME')
            }
            if ("${BRANCH_NAME}"=="develop" || ("${BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("release")))
            {    
                sshagent (credentials: ['GitSSHLOGIN']) {
                    sh("git tag -a PBCS_${BRANCH_NAME}_${ReleaseNumber}_${BUILD_NUMBER} -m 'Tag the build ${BRANCH_NAME}_${ReleaseNumber}_${BUILD_NUMBER}'")
                    sh('git push --tags origin $BRANCH_NAME')
                }
            }
    }
```

Below is the error we are getting.

```
+ git push --tags origin release/21.04

Could not create directory '/c/Jenkins/jobs/branches/release-21-04.3rkqb4/workspace/nullnull/.ssh'.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```